# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'onChat' was never awaited del self.m[i] RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord, asyncio

На данный момент пишу irc бота для сервера Minecraft. Нужна помощь с mineflayer. Попытался сделать вывод чата в Discord канал, не получилось

Код:

```
@On(minebot, 'chat')
@client.event
async def onChat(ctx, user, message, this, *rest):
    await ctx.channel.send(f'{user} -> {message}')
```

Выдает ошибку

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'onChat' was never awaited
  del self.m[i]
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение..

Comment: я новичок, в любом случае не выводится ничего в канал с ботом

Comment: А вы попробуйте убрать `async`, поскольку предупреждение об этом и говорит